Is google chart geo with "markers" paid?
I need to use google geo charts with the markers to build a world map chart, and create something like this

But the docs say "Note: Because markers require geocoding, you'll need a mapsApiKey."
However it's not clear if its is paid or not.
..............................................................

It's not paid. You need a key, which is free for most private users, so that Google can track usage to prevent abuse. The docs message you referenced gives you the URL for Load the Libraries in the very next line, which in turn links to Get a Key/Authentication.
